# Using symbolic variable in boolean algebra with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, boolean-logic, symbolic-math

How do I substitute the symbolic variables in a boolean expression? I am having this problem and can't solve it even in the example below.

```
syms a
syms b

o = myand(a, b);
```

where

```
function o = myand(a, b)
    o = and(a, b);
end
```

I also tried the below but got an "Invalid Operand" error.

```
subs(o, [a, b], [1, 1])
```

I also tried using the `not()` function (one input) and it worked. I read MATLAB documentation and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, so for the [`and`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/and.html) expression from the Symbolic Toolbox in MATLAB, it requires an actual mathematical expression for each operand.  The reason why the `not` operator worked for you is because it is able to take in numbers, vectors, anything that is numeric in addition to symbolic expressions.  From the [`not`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/not.html) documentation:

> A — Input
> number | vector | matrix | array | symbolic number | symbolic variable | symbolic array | symbolic function | symbolic expression

Compared with `and`:

> A - Input
> symbolic equations | symbolic inequalities | symbolic expressions | symbolic arrays

So the `and` function actually does not take in single values when you do substitutions.  Also, I suspect that if you just use `a` and `b` as is, it doesn't actually understand that if `a` is not zero, this should be true. The same goes for `b`.  A workaround is to define the function, but condition both variables so that anything greater than 0 is true, else false.  This should still hold within the binary universe:

```
function o = myand(a, b)
    o = and(a > 0, b > 0);
end
```

For this to be more compact, we can define an anonymous function instead:

```
myand = @(a, b) and(a > 0, b > 0);
```

Now if you try it, it should work:

```
syms a b;
myand = @(a, b) and(a > 0, b > 0);
o = myand(a, b);
c = subs(o, [a, b], [1, 1]);
```

We get for `c`:

```
>> c
 
c =
 
0 < 1
```

... so yeah, that's technically true.  We can convert this into a numeric result:

```
>> double(c)

ans =

     1
```

Comment: and now MATLAB docs makes sense to me. Thank you!! Thats not the first time you helpe me. I looked your profile and I remenber that I watched your communications systems's classes.

Comment: Wow! That was from a long time ago! I remember I made these videos private only to students in that class, but I was encouraged to make them public by the students. They found them to be helpful so I decided to release them in the hopes of others finding them useful. I can see they were right! I'm glad I helped you in the past!